# how to crete array like below in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to create an array like `[['India', 6],['USA', 3]]`

using below data

```
     [
{ _id: 'India', count: 6 },
  { _id: 'USA', count: 3 }
   ]
```

Comment: [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var d = [{
    _id: 'India',
    count: 6
  },
  {
    _id: 'USA',
    count: 3
  }
];

var output = d.map(function(ele) {
  return [ele._id, ele.count]
});

console.log(output);
```

If you're open to a solution using ES6, it looks much cleaner using [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```js
let d = [{
    _id: 'India',
    count: 6
  },
  {
    _id: 'USA',
    count: 3
  }
];

// Destructure every array element into { _id, count }
// Pass an expression in the RHS that just creates an array using _id and count
let output = d.map(({ _id, count }) => [_id, count])

console.log(output);
```